# How can I speed up my VBA code with a long For Next loop that reformats a user-pasted text block?

Tags: excel, vba, refactoring

My code will do what I want it to, but not efficiently.  The user will paste exactly five columns & a variable number of rows onto worksheet "Resp" in the range C:G.  An incremental number is added per row in B range. C range will take a First & Last name and change to Last, First.  D & F ranges currently only check for text length & shrink-to-fit if exceeding certain number.  E range replaces 1 of 2 possible strings with either a Y or N.  Last, G range formats the date to "m-dd-yy" from "mm-dd-yyyy".

The problem is that it takes approx 2.2s per 10 rows pasted (50 cells total).  I am experimenting with new possibilities, but could use extra eyes on my code to see what can be refactored.

I've done a few Google searches, read over the docs, and looked over some of the other SO problems, but nothing is close enough to what I have here.

```
Option Base 1

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Or Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Or Target.Columns.Count <> 5 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else: If VBA.IsEmpty(Target.Cells(1, 1)) = True Then Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim nSheet As Worksheet
    Dim nRange(5) As Range
    Dim bRange As Range
    'The reason for this bRange is that I decided I needed it and don't want 
    'to update the range array just yet, long task



    Dim nLen As Integer
    Dim numLast As Long
    Dim fnStr() As String
    Dim rplStr As String

    Set nSheet = Worksheets("Resp")

    Set bRange = nSheet.Range("B" & (Target.Row) & ":B" & (Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1))
    Set nRange(1) = nSheet.Range("C" & (Target.Row) & ":C" & (Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1))
    Set nRange(2) = nSheet.Range("D" & (Target.Row) & ":D" & (Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1))
    Set nRange(3) = nSheet.Range("E" & (Target.Row) & ":E" & (Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1))
    Set nRange(4) = nSheet.Range("F" & (Target.Row) & ":F" & (Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1))
    Set nRange(5) = nSheet.Range("G" & (Target.Row) & ":G" & (Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1))
    'The intent is for the user to paste material that follows a certain format and is exactly 5 columns in length
    'Right now they must paste in C:G, but I might change this to make it more user-friendly
    'This range array probably isnt necessary, but does that affect execution speed as opposed
    'to using a single Range variable that gets adjusted frequently?

    If VBA.IsNumeric(bRange.Cells(0, 1)) = False Then
        numLast = 0

    Else
        numLast = bRange.Cells(0, 1).Value

    End If

    For i = 0 To (Target.Rows.Count - 1)
        'If it is possible to do some of these tasks as a batch rather than per cell
        'that seems to be what is lagging this down

        bRange.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = numLast + i + 1
        'Keeps track of the last number already on the sheet so we know whats next

        fnStr() = Split(nRange(1).Cells(i + 1, 1))
        'Do this for every cell in C that was pasted over
        'Rearranges first name last name to last name, first name

        On Error Resume Next
        'Strings that do not have a space will cause error, so I took a temporary shortcut rather than handling error
        nRange(1).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = fnStr(1) & ", " & fnStr(0)

        On Error GoTo 0
        nLen = Len(nRange(2).Cells(i + 1, 1))
       'Length of each cells text to determine if it will be shrunk

        If nLen > 60 Then nRange(2).Cells(i + 1, 1).ShrinkToFit = True
        'Could this be done over the entire column or does it need to be done 
        'one-at-a-time

        If nRange(3).Cells(i + 1, 1).Text = "Read Answer" Then
            rplStr = Replace(nRange(3).Cells(i + 1, 1), "Read Answer", "Y")
            nRange(3).Cells(i + 1, 1) = rplStr
        Else
            rplStr = Replace(nRange(3).Cells(i + 1, 1), "We'll notify you when they answer.", "N")
            nRange(3).Cells(i + 1, 1) = rplStr
        End If
        'This is probably the worst part of it so Im experimenting with other options now

    Next
    'The rest of the code is irrelevant
```

Preferably, it should executed much faster than the current 2.2s / 10 rows.  I don't know how much time could be saved, but I made comments in the code where I think the problems might be.

Comment: The typical advice is to minimise the number of times you access information in Excel.  So copy the range to a VBA array.  Do your text manipulations in the VBA array, then copy the array back to Excel.

Comment: I will try that and respond later with details.

Comment: I figured out that turning Application.Calculation to xlManual fixed this.